# How to fetch the data from Mysql Database using multiple spinner selection

Tags: c#, php, android, mysql, xamarin.android

I have written a PHP code to create a Mysql database(online) (as a table) as shown.

[image]

I have also created a page with spinners as same as the headings of my table data.

[image]

Now I want to filter my data using these spinners like, If I select "Country: Germany" from "Country" spinner and "Course: Master Degree" from "Course" spinner, then I should get the filtered list of university details(i.e., details of the universities which are located in Germany and offer bachelor degree).
For that, I am trying to create a connection between online data which I have imported into my code as Jsondata and Spinner event handler but I cannot do it.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: your mean that you want to filter data from MySql database, then load these data in Android?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT  Yes!! Can you suggest me some ideas?

Comment: About connecting online mysql database, I find one video that you can take a look:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOZ8HNJMXXg